# Firebase Authentication Endless Loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, processing.js

I wrote a program using Firebase Authentication that I want to redirect to a Google SignIn page if a user isn’t signed in, but not to redirect if a user is signed in. Everything works great except for when it goes back to my page after the Google Sign In, it redirects back to the SignIn after only a couple of seconds. Here’s my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
var uid;
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var xv = 0;
var yv = 0;
var xpos = 200;
var ypos = 200;
var changeRef = firebase.database().ref();
var keys = [];

if (user != null) {
uid = currentUser.uid;
firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid).set({
xpos: xpos,
ypos: ypos
});
} else {
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
if (result.credential) {
// This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the      Google API.
var token = result.credential.accessToken;
// ...
}
// The signed-in user info.
user = result.user;
}).catch(function(error) {
// Handle Errors here.
var errorCode = error.code;
var errorMessage = error.message;
// The email of the user's account used.
var email = error.email;
// The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
var credential = error.credential;
// ...
});
}
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);

});
```

Comment: You'll have better luck if you narrow your problem down a bit. For example this really doesn't have anything to do with Processing.js. You should also really try to use proper indentation so your code is easier to read.

Comment: I actually just fixed it, but you’re right. I put the processing.js tag because that’s in my full code, but I didn’t include that part. And I’m not sure how to mark text as code when it’s indented; doesn’t it just have 4 spaces? Thanks for the tips!

Comment: If you figured out an answer to the question, you might want to post an answer or just delete the question. But for future reference, you can definitely include indentation in a code block. Just paste the whole (correctly indented) code block, then highlight it and press the code button. That will add 4 spaces to each line, and your originally formatting will be maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user is signed in you are calling both signInWithRedirect and getRedirectResult in parallel, that is why you are stuck in an endless loop:

```
} else {
  firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
  firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
```

You can either attach the signInWithRedirect to a click or pull it out from this block to the (user not signed in) block.